# How did Harry break the Elder Wand in Deathly Hallows Part 2?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

The Elder Wand in the Harry Potter series was considered to be the most powerful wand, does that make it indestructible? How did Harry just snap the Elder Wand as if it was a thin wooden stick?

Comment: Because it was just a thin wooden stick.

Comment: if he was able to snap it, it obviously wasn't indestructible.

Comment: although he in fact doesn't snap it in the book, he just returns it to the one that owned it before its previous owner, well the guy's small marble quarters anyway...